# Does the Unity compiler not fully support named parameters?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

The following code compiles just fine in Visual Studio, but in Unity (4.6.x) it creates a compiler error:

```
public class ErrorTest 
{
    void DoSomething(bool a = true, bool f = true) {  }
    void DoSomething(int b, bool f = true) {  }
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
       DoSomething(f: false);
    }
}
```

The call to DoSomething is what makes the compiler choke. The question is why, there's really no ambiguity.

---

The console output when Unity chokes like this:

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:
Unhandled Exception: Mono.CSharp.InternalErrorException: Internal error

  at Mono.CSharp.MethodGroupExpr.IsApplicable (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec, Mono.CSharp.Arguments& arguments, Int32 arg_count, System.Reflection.MethodBase& method, System.Boolean& params_expanded_form) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.MethodGroupExpr.OverloadResolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec, Mono.CSharp.Arguments& Arguments, Boolean may_fail, Location loc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Invocation.DoResolveOverload (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Invocation.DoResolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec, ResolveFlags flags) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Expression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.ResolveContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.ExpressionStatement.ResolveStatement (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.StatementExpression.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.Block.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext ec) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.Resolve (Mono.CSharp.FlowBranching parent, Mono.CSharp.BlockContext rc, Mono.CSharp.ParametersCompiled ip, IMethodData md) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Please show the complete compile-time error. Do simple cases using named arguments / default parameters (*all* parameters are named...) work? Have you tried Unity 5?

Comment: 1.) Yes, I use named arguments and default params all the time. 2.) Unity 5: Not yet

Comment: Odd - it compiles under "normal" Mono 3.12.

Answer (score 0):

[There was/is apparently a bug](http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/combining-namespaces-mbs-with-default-params-break) where combining the use of namespaces and default parameters caused an internal error like this. It was allegedly fixed in 4.5, but from the comments it has been allegedly fixed before. You might try eliminating the namespace declaration in your class as an experiment to see if that bug is what you're experiencing.